# Check user access with middleware string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware, policies

I have a String with a middleware rule (like in routes):

```
$middleware = "can:index,App\Models\Order";
```

Is there any possiblity to check if a given user has access with this middleware rule?

Comment: I can honestly say I have never made / used a mware like that before :|

Comment: You can use it with routes. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-middleware

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that. I'm not sure what your problem is though?

Comment: Ah thanks! I have always preferred using the `Route::group(['middleware', => ['whatevs']], function()` method and place all routes that within it.

Comment: @Jonathon I want to apply this rule  on a given user. Not on a route.

Comment: So given a `User` object and an `Order` object, you want to see if a that user can `index` the order? In a controller for example?

Answer (score 0):

That is how laravel policies define authorization rules in middleware. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-middleware

Create a policy class for the model you are authorizing then register the policy to model.

Comment: I want to apply the middleware rule  on a given user. Not on a route.

Comment: I see, you can authorize using a user model, just not using that exact syntax. Have you read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-the-user-model

Comment: I'd still recommend registering policies. They can handle authorization automatically for you. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#registering-policies

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to see if a given user is authorized to carry out a certain action in many different ways. One is by using the middleware in your question and attaching it to a route or group. Here are some other ways:

Using the `can` method on the `User` object. The `can` method is inherited from the `Authorizable` trait (So it's not limited just to users):

```
if ($user->can('index', 'App\Models\Order')) {
    // User is allowed to index orders.
}
```

Using the `authorize` method on a controller. The `authorize` method is inherited from the `AuthorizesRequests` trait (So this is not limited to just controller). This method throws an exception if authorization fails:

```
$this->authorize('index', 'App\Models\Order');
```

In a view, it is possible to use the `@can` Blade directive to see if a user is authorized to carry out the given action:

```
@can('index', 'App\Models\Order')
    This user can index orders.
@endcan
```

If you have that specific string, you could do a little bit of manipulation to extract the bits you need and then pass it to one of the above methods:

```
$middleware = "can:index,App\Models\Order";
list($rule, $parameters) = explode(':', $middleware);
list($ability, $model) = explode(',', $parameters);

if ($user->can($ability, $model)) {
    // User can index orders.
}
```

Of course it would be wise to do more error checking etc.